# Why struct with auto_ptr and explicit destructor unable to swap

Tags: c++, visual-studio

look at this code. Test struct has a auto_ptr and explicit destructor. When I build this code in Windows environment (Visual Studio 2017 professional) **with error level 4**, it shows this warning.

`warning C4239: nonstandard extension used: 'argument': conversion from 'Test' to 'Test &'
note: A non-const reference may only be bound to an lvalue; copy constructor takes a reference to non-const`

What I understand is `std::swap` accept the reference for the `Test` class and unable to cast instance to reference. If I remove destructor or auto_ptr warning disappear. Any idea what is the cause?

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <memory>
typedef struct Test
{
public:
    int a;
    std::auto_ptr<Test> b;
    ~Test()
    {
    }
} Test_Type;


int main()
{
    Test_Type arr[2];
    arr[0].a = 5;
    arr[1].a = 3;
    std::swap(arr[0], arr[1]);
}
```

Comment: Which MSVC version are we talking about?

Comment: 2017 professional. here is the explanation from MS https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-warnings/compiler-warning-level-4-c4239 though I couldn't figure out how to match in to my scenario.

Comment: Out of curiosity - why `auto_ptr`?

Comment: @Nim: This is a legacy product. I have just simplified the scenario from a large code set to this few lines.

Comment: The behaviour is the same if you substitute `unique_ptr` for `auto_ptr` and explicitly declare the destructor. The primary reason is that this disables all implicitly declared constructors/assignment operator (see rule of three before and now rule of five) For example, with `unique_ptr` this fails because the user defined destructor prevents the move constructor and move assign from being generated, which then prevents the swap. If you explicitly define the move constructor/assignment and `default` them, then this will compile with `unique_ptr`. `auto_ptr` is just broken.

Comment: Only way around this - if you cannot change to `unique_ptr` would be to implement your own `swap` - which explicitly swaps the members of `Test`, and for the `auto_ptr` do `release()` and assign appropriately. But - honestly - just fix this code and use `unique_ptr`, `auto_ptr` will be removed in C++17 AFAIK..

Comment: sorry, I didn't get what is the mean of `see rule of three before and now rule of five`

Comment: See this: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three

Comment: Another question is why it delete all the default constructors ans operators when destructor and smart pointer together? it works fine when only explicit destructor there.

Comment: @NayanaAdassuriya Declaration of non-default destructor disables autogeneration of move constructor. And swapping requires move constructor when uniqe_ptr is present (and probably in MS implementation the same holds for auto_ptr -- looks like non-statndard extension, because standard auto_ptr does not invoke moves)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`auto_ptr` is weird because its "copy" constructor takes the source by non-const reference, since it needs to modify it.

That forces `Test`'s implicitly-declared copy constructor to also take the source by non-`const` reference.

A user-declared destructor suppresses the implicit declaration of the move constructor.

Therefore inside of `swap`, when it does the equivalent of `Test_Type tmp = std::move(arr[0]);`, the only constructor available is the copy constructor taking non-const reference, and the only reason that constructor can even be used is the nonstandard extension mentioned in the warning, permitting such a reference to bind to an rvalue.

Take out `auto_ptr`, and `Test`'s implicitly declared constructor will now take a `const` reference, which does bind to rvalues.

Take out the destructor, and `Test` will now have an implicitly-declared move constructor, which can be used for the move.

Note that the move constructor of `Test`, perhaps surprisingly, should not be implicitly defined as deleted. While `auto_ptr` doesn't have a move constructor, the test is whether overload resolution succeeds for the direct-initialization from an rvalue `auto_ptr`. It does, thanks to the `auto_ptr_ref` shenanigans. Both Clang and GCC got this wrong, while MSVC got it right (!).

Everything above applies to the assignment operator as well.

Comment: Thank you for nice explanation and surprisingly Both Clang and GCC got this wrong, while MSVC got it right. btw, is this behavior define in standards?